# Launcher Icons stop working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, icons, hud

I have the problem that sometimes my launcher Icons will get left-click-unresronsive. Right click will open the context menu, though.

Starting applications via the HUD works fine, but the launcher Icons seem to freeze. Even when an application is running, I can't get it to the front by clicking on the launcher.

For info: one customization I made is replacing Nautilus with Nemo as the default file explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using multiple monitors and have your launcher only displaying on one. Try showing your launcher on all displays.

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: No problem, FYI this way fixed in a recent update. I'm back to displaying my launcher on one display and it's working as expected.

Comment: @DevenK, I don't think it's completely resolved for everybody. I just experienced this for the first time today, on a completely up-to-date system.

Comment: This isnt really a "fix" but some other methodology that allows you to circumvent the bug. I have my launcher on all displays, and this happens every so often on one of my launchers - not both.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this today (Ubuntu 64 16.04 LTS) I could alt-tab between active windows and use them okay; however the sidebar and task bar (with volume control) ignored all clicks; I couldn't find anything that might have been blocking it.

I didn't want to reboot as I had loads of stuff open; but when I locked the screen (for lunchtime) and then logged in afterwards it was working again, so that may be a fix for someone else.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem sometimes on Ubuntu 16.04. Locking and unlocking helps, but it is annoying. Didn't you find permanent solution?

Comment: In my case, "lock then unlock" didn't fix it, but "logout then login" fixed it, but all my programs where closed